# How to know if an array with numbers (zeros) is being seen as an empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I work with an array of numbers and each number represents a color expect for number zero. Like you see in my code, I draw an array of rectangles and with number zero I clear out the rectangles which becomes an empty place. How can I know if my array is empty? If there are still zeros in my array how can this be an empty array?

```js
 var canvas = document.getElementById("mijnCanvas");
 var mijnObject = canvas.getContext("2d");

 function tekenenObjecten() {
  makenMuur();
 }
 setInterval(tekenenObjecten, 20);

 var stenenPerRij = 27;
 var steenHoogte = 20;
 var steenBreedte = canvas.width/stenenPerRij;

 var stenen = [
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
  [0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,7,2,2,2,2,2,1,0],
  [0,1,1,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,6,1,1,1,1,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,1,3,0,0,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,2,2,2,0,1,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,1,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,3,0,0,1],
  [1,1,1,1,0,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,4,2,2,0,0,1,0,1,0,1],
  [1,0,0,1,0,2,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1],
  [1,0,0,1,0,2,0,0,2,2,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,2,2,2,2,0,1,0,0,0,1],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
  [0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,0],
  [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
 ];

 function makenMuur() {
  for(var i = 0; i < stenen.length; i = i+1) {
   for(var j = 0; j < stenen[i].length; j = j+1) {
    tekenenStenen(j,i,stenen[i][j]);
   }
  }
 }

 function tekenenStenen(x,y,stenen) {
  switch(stenen) {
   case 1:
    mijnObject.fillStyle = "#0D0D0D";
    break;
   case 2:
    mijnObject.fillStyle = "#CCCCCC";
    break;
   case 3:
    mijnObject.fillStyle = "#0D0D0D";
    break;
   case 4:
    mijnObject.fillStyle = "#CCCCCC";
    break;
   default:
    mijnObject.clearRect(0, 0, steenBreedte, steenHoogte);
    break;
  }
  if(stenen) {
   mijnObject.beginPath();
   mijnObject.strokeStyle = "#000000";
   mijnObject.rect(x*steenBreedte, y*steenHoogte, steenBreedte, steenHoogte);
   mijnObject.fill();
   mijnObject.stroke();
   mijnObject.closePath();
  }
 }
```

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="mijnCanvas" width="1200" height="900"></canvas>
    <script src="../BrickSmasher.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you mean that the equivalent of "empty" here is that giant array filled with all 0s?

Comment: @SterlingArcher yes, I make the game BrickBreaker and these rectangles are bricks, the numbers are filled with a color expect for number 0 which is cleared out. The ball touches the colored bricks but not the color zero... but how to know if the Array is empty?

Comment: If you mean only the individual inner Arrays, then `!arr.some(Boolean)` would do it.

Comment: If you mean all the arrays in the outer Array, then `!outerArray.some(function(arr) { return !arr.some(Boolean) })`, or using ES6 arrow functions: `!outerArray.some(arr => !arr.some(Boolean))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) you can check if in all rows, all columns are 0. The good thing about this solution is that if the first row has something not a 0 on first column, it will return false without checking the rest of the array

```
var isEmpty = stenen.every(function(row){ // does every row have all 0 in its columns?
    return row.every(function(col){ // do all columns in a row have all 0?
        return col == 0
    })
})
```

As @DonovanM pointed out, with ES6 you can just do:

```
let isEmpty = stenen.every(row => row.every(col => col === 0))
```

Comment: The above in ES6 would simply be `let isEmpty = stenen.every(row => row.every(col => col === 0))`

Comment: @DonovanM Thank you very much. That is a very good method to use.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to iterate over your array, sum up all the numbers, and return it. (see the docs for how it does it specifically). If the `sum` is 0, your array is empty.

```
let sum = stenen.reduce((x,y) => x+y); //sums up (using an arrow function) the array 
if (!stenen) // the sum is 0 and it's "empty"
```

Note: this is ES6 code. This translates (from a single line implied return) to:

```
var sum = stenen.reduce(function(x,y) {
    return x+y;
});
```

Comment: Nice and clean. I dig it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function which checks for a non-zero value anywhere in the array.

```
function isEmpty(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] !== 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Or a faster version which caches the lengths of the arrays.

```
function isEmpty(arr) {
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    var subArr = arr[i];
    for (var j = 0, len2 = subArr.length; j < len2; j++) {
      if (subArr[j] !== 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I think you left something out :) The second `isEmpty` is an infinite loop with `for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i++)`.

Comment: @DonovanM You're right! Thanks for the catch. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

you could use filter as you loop through each array to check for a length above 0:

```
function check(matrix) {
  for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    var len = matrix[i].filter(function(el) {
      return el > 0;
    }).length;
    if (len) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/cukole/1/edit?js,console)